# call a android-function from the PC

Tags: java, android, usb, remote-access

I would like to call some functions in my `Android-app` from the `PC`.

On the `PC` I would like to write a short `java` or `C` program.

Simplified, I think on something like this call on the PC:

```
myApp.Appfunction ();
```

and then the

```
Appfunction(){
}
```

in my app on the android-phone just simply called.

Is it possible?

Is there any way to achieve this

The interface is still open.

I have a **Samsung Galaxy S3** so there are a lot possible interfaces:

**NFC, Bluetooth, USB, WiFi Direct**

I prefer an `USB` connection but if something else is easier to implement, I also work with other interfaces.

Thanks in advance for the answer

Comment: yes you can do with socket programs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a server on your PC and wait for a socket connection you'll do througt android.
So, your api becomes:

```
public void pcFunction(){
          //estabilish a socket connect
          //send a message "cmd function" to server
}
```

on the server

```
//receives message and parse it
switch(cmd){
     case fun1:
         callFunction1();
         break;
     case fun2:
         //
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help but I need a network connection for your method, right? Is there no way with USB?

Comment: Usb,wifi,bluetooth are just ways to make data flow from your smartphone to the pc, you can imagine these as streets. Now, if you send data you need a "destination" and this destination is a server program which will listen for messages. If you do this with usb you'll have to write a server which, instead of a socket, listens on a serial interface but the substance does not change